# UseOpenIdConnectServer is not working

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openid-provider, openiddict

I just updated my dotnet core webapi application from **netcoreapp1.0** to **netcoreapp2.0**. I am using openiddict for authentication and authorization based on this [sample](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/PasswordFlow).

***ConfigureServices*** method :

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
               {
                   options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
               });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {                
                options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=SERVER1;Database=DB1;User Id=BLAHBLAH;Password=BLAHBLAHBLAH;");                
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
                options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;                
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict(options =>
            {                
                options.AddEntityFrameworkCoreStores<ApplicationDbContext>();                
                options.AddMvcBinders();
                options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/connect/token");
                options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                options.DisableHttpsRequirement();
                options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddOAuthValidation();

        }
```

***Configure*** method :

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseCors(b => b.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());    

            app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(configuration => {                
                configuration.AllowInsecureHttp = true;                                    
                configuration.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
            });               
            app.UseAuthentication();                
            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

The ***AuthorizationProvider*** class :

```
    public sealed class AuthorizationProvider : OpenIdConnectServerProvider
    {            
        public AuthorizationProvider()
        {

        }

        public override async Task ApplyTokenResponse(ApplyTokenResponseContext context)
        {        
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Error))
            {
                var role = context.Ticket.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role).Value;
                var userName = context.Ticket.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Type == OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name).Value;
                context.Response["role"] = role;
                context.Response["userName"] = userName;
                context.Response[".issued"] = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");
                context.Response[".expires"] = DateTime.Now.AddHours(8).ToUniversalTime().ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'");    
            }

            return;
        }
    }
```

The following code is not working :

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(configuration => {                
    configuration.AllowInsecureHttp = true;                
    configuration.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
});
```

It says *'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseOpenIdConnectServer' and no extension method 'UseOpenIdConnectServer' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

How do I resolve it? What is the alternative method to add a custom provider?

Answer (score 2):

As per [github page with examples](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server)

The correct way of doing this in `Startup.cs` is as follow. (`pasting my sample code for your reference. You can re-factor based on your need)`
It should be inside `ConfigureServices` method

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "ServerCookie";
    })
    .AddCookie("ServerCookie", options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "ServerCookie";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/logout");
    })
    .AddOAuthValidation()
    .AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
    {
        options.ProviderType = typeof(AuthorizationProvider);

        // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
        options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = "/connect/authorize";
        options.LogoutEndpointPath = "/connect/logout";
        options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Login");//"/connect/token";
        options.UserinfoEndpointPath = "/connect/userinfo";

        // Note: see AuthorizationController.cs for more
        // information concerning ApplicationCanDisplayErrors.
        options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
        options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;

        // Note: to override the default access token format and use JWT, assign AccessTokenHandler:
        //
        // options.AccessTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
        // {
        //     InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
        //     OutboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        // };
        //
        // Note: when using JWT as the access token format, you have to register a signing key.
        //
        // You can register a new ephemeral key, that is discarded when the application shuts down.
        // Tokens signed using this key are automatically invalidated and thus this method
        // should only be used during development:
        //
        // options.SigningCredentials.AddEphemeralKey();
        //
        // On production, using a X.509 certificate stored in the machine store is recommended.
        // You can generate a self-signed certificate using Pluralsight's self-cert utility:
        // https://s3.amazonaws.com/pluralsight-free/keith-brown/samples/SelfCert.zip
        //
        // options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate("7D2A741FE34CC2C7369237A5F2078988E17A6A75");
        //
        // Alternatively, you can also store the certificate as an embedded .pfx resource
        // directly in this assembly or in a file published alongside this project:
        //
        // options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate(
        //     assembly: typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
        //     resource: "Mvc.Server.Certificate.pfx",
        //     password: "Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server");
    });
    services.AddScoped<AuthorizationProvider>();
```

Then inside your configure method

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

where app is `IApplicationBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 2.0 has a new model for authentication and Identity which simplifies configuration by using services and below is the migration guide

[Migrating Authentication and Identity to ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x)

in Configure method change this

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(configuration => {                
    configuration.AllowInsecureHttp = true;                
    configuration.Provider = new AuthorizationProvider();
});
```

To this

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

and in ConfigureServices add the below code

```
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    options.Authority = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"];
    options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"];
});
```

Comment: That would only add OpenIdConnect to the application. But how do I add a custom provider to OpenIdConnect as I've mentioned in UseOpenIdConnectServer?

Comment: try finding available configuration with the AddOpenIdConnect options

Answer (score 0):

Look here

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(ApplicationContext));
            });

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "ServerCookie";
        })

        .AddCookie("ServerCookie", options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "ServerCookie";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/signin");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/signout");
        })

        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "560027070069-37ldt4kfuohhu3m495hk2j4pjp92d382.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            options.ClientSecret = "n2Q-GEw9RQjzcRbU3qhfTj8f";
        })

        .AddTwitter(options =>
        {
            options.ConsumerKey = "6XaCTaLbMqfj6ww3zvZ5g";
            options.ConsumerSecret = "Il2eFzGIrYhz6BWjYhVXBPQSfZuS4xoHpSSyD9PI";
        })

        .AddOAuthValidation()

        .AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.ProviderType = typeof(AuthorizationProvider);

            // Enable the authorization, logout, token and userinfo endpoints.
            options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = "/connect/authorize";
            options.LogoutEndpointPath = "/connect/logout";
            options.TokenEndpointPath = "/connect/token";
            options.UserinfoEndpointPath = "/connect/userinfo";

            // Note: see AuthorizationController.cs for more
            // information concerning ApplicationCanDisplayErrors.
            options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;

            // Note: to override the default access token format and use JWT, assign AccessTokenHandler:
            //
            // options.AccessTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler
            // {
            //     InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            //     OutboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            // };
            //
            // Note: when using JWT as the access token format, you have to register a signing key.
            //
            // You can register a new ephemeral key, that is discarded when the application shuts down.
            // Tokens signed using this key are automatically invalidated and thus this method
            // should only be used during development:
            //
            // options.SigningCredentials.AddEphemeralKey();
            //
            // On production, using a X.509 certificate stored in the machine store is recommended.
            // You can generate a self-signed certificate using Pluralsight's self-cert utility:
            // https://s3.amazonaws.com/pluralsight-free/keith-brown/samples/SelfCert.zip
            //
            // options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate("7D2A741FE34CC2C7369237A5F2078988E17A6A75");
            //
            // Alternatively, you can also store the certificate as an embedded .pfx resource
            // directly in this assembly or in a file published alongside this project:
            //
            // options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate(
            //     assembly: typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
            //     resource: "Mvc.Server.Certificate.pfx",
            //     password: "Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server");
        });

        services.AddScoped<AuthorizationProvider>();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    }
```

https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/blob/dev/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Startup.cs#L29